# Cannot install packages in sdk manager

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I installed Android Studio because I had this problem with Eclipse, but the problem remains:
I cannot create an AVD because apparently the package `Android ARM EABY v7a System Image` is not installed, so I opened the SDK manager and tried to install that package together with a few more and I get these errors:

```
Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp
```

and

```
Skipping 'Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 20, revision1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform
```

and

```
Android 4.4W, API 20, revision 1' which was not installed.
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran Eclipse as administrator and was able to install files without errors; previously, when I tried installing the same files while Eclipse was run in 'regular' mode, the errors popped up.  I didn't have to remove and reinstall Eclipse.  Running as admin worked.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I did this with Android Studio and it worked fine. I'm not sure this is (or should be) the "correct" solution, but it is A solution.

Comment: Running eclipse as administrator sorted a problem I was having, very similar to this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Then I ran the SDK manager again and now I get those error messages: URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp\tools_r23.0.2-windows.zip (Access is denied)

run as administrator, the problem resolved.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. The reason being is because the directory is under Program Files directory, and by default the process requires administrator privileges to modify/add files in that path.

Answer (score 0):

Does `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp` exist?

If "no," does creating it help?
If "yes," does temporarily renaming it (perhaps to 'temp-backup') help?

Comment: The folder temp didn't exist, so I created it. Then I ran the SDK manager again and now I get those error messages: URL not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp\tools_r23.0.2-windows.zip (Access is denied)         and     Skipping 'Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 20, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 4.4W, API 20, revision 1' which was not installed.

Comment: No, it didn't unfortunately.

Comment: I did remove Eclipse, Android Studio, cleared all the files related to Android, made sure that the Path in environment variables was correct, reinstalled JDK, Android Studio and ran it as administrator. Now it seems to be working....

Comment: glad you got it up and running. that was a weird bug.

Answer (score 0):

For others coming across this problem, here's what I did..
I created the folder, and based on experience, permissions can be an issue. 
The folder I created was, as Android Studio prompted, "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\temp`".

After creating the folder, I simply right clicked, selected `properties`, and went to the `Security` tab inside the folder properties window.  From there, I clicked on `Advanced` and added full control permissions for "Everyone".  Obviously it's not great to have it wide open to everyone but hey, it worked - I will apply appropriate group permissions at a later stage.  After creating the global full control permissions, the SDK manager could start downloading the packages.

I noticed, after this, that the sdk manager still had issues moving files to other folders inside the SDK folder, so I just applied the correct permissions for the whole folder.

I hope this helps someone else who might be having the same problem.

Comment: I hope nobody follows suggestion to open security holes in their system like this.

Comment: People should be using Cypine's answer. Run the program as administrator. This is required because by default only administrator ran processes can modify directories and files under `C:\Program Files` (or the (x86) equivalent.